# Using wordpress and advanced custom fields, how can I use a subfield for my meta query?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using Wordpress with the Advanced Custom Fields Pro plugin and I'm trying to get all the posts that have a date field that is after today's date. I looked at this example https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/date-picker/ and that works fine except that my field is a subfield of a repeater field. And I have some trouble making a meta query for that. I tried using `_%_` for the subfield but then I read here https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/meta_query-for-a-group-field-sub-field/ that I can just use an underscore for the subfield. But posts still aren't coming up with any results. I tried checking the date from just a single post and it appears to be working correctly. I also read here [advancedcustomfields.com/resources/date-picker](http://advancedcustomfields.com/resources/date-picker) that the date is always stored as Ymd in the database. I tried doing it with another field that isn't a subfield and that worked, so the problem lies with the subfield I think `'key' => 'date_startdate',`

I am using the date picker as a subfield.

```
function do_get_upcoming($atts = [])
    {
        $defaultLimit = 8;
        $limit = $atts["limit"] != null ? $atts["limit"] : $defaultLimit;

        $today = date('Ymd');

        $posts = get_posts(array(
            'numberposts'   => $limit,
            'post_type'     => 'events',
            'meta_query' => array(
                 array(
                    'key'     => 'date_startdate',
                    'value'   => $today,
                    ‘type’ => ‘DATE’
                    'compare' => '>',
                )
            ),
        ));

        echo count($posts);
    }
    add_shortcode('get_upcoming','do_get_upcoming');
```

[screenshot subfield](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14C3I.png)

Comment: The fact that it worked with another field shows it's a not a coding issue! How about you check your Date Format in ACF fields management? I do remember there is a displayed format and a computed one.

Comment: There is no option for a computed one, from what I read with acf pro it's always Ymd when working with queries. I added a screenshot to the question.

Comment: Here https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/date-picker/ it says Please note that the value is always saved as Ymd (YYYYMMDD) in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. Subfields can be accessed by adding `_0_` so you'll get `'key' => 'date_0_startdate'`

Comment: My mistake it's been a while I came across such problem! I solved it by looking into the database. My client wanted to store those dates with other fields into a separate Sqlite database... It's weird how they store that in options table. It made my task more challenging while syncing between Mysql and Sqlite.